# Linear transformation and idempotence

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

I was wondering... Is there any way to formally  prove that given a linear transformation $L: V \rightarrow V$ over a vector space $V$ if $\text{ker}(L^2)=\text{ker}(L)$ $\leftrightarrow$ $L^2 = L$, hence $L$ is idempotent? This reasoning can be obviously extended to the case  $\text{im}(L^2)=\text{im}(L)$. I would say that things are this way by definition... Any suggestion or comment would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well two linear transformations are said to be equal if and only if the matrix generated by the linear transformations are equal

Answer (score 1):

No, $\ker(L^2)=\ker(L)$ just means that $\ker(L) \cap \operatorname{Im}(L)=\{0\}$. For example, if $V$ is vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and $L:V \to V$ linear transformation such that 
$$L(x)=\lambda x,\quad \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$$
then $\ker(L)=\ker(L^2)$, but $L \neq L^2$, except when $\lambda \in \{0,1\}$.

Indeed, $L^2(x)=\lambda^2 x$. When $\lambda \neq 0$ then 
$$\ker(L)=\ker(L^2)=\{0\}, \quad \operatorname{Im}(L)=\operatorname{Im}(L^2)=V$$
and when $\lambda=0$,
$$\ker(L)=\ker(L^2)=V, \quad \operatorname{Im}(L)=\operatorname{Im}(L^2)=\{0\}$$
so in both cases $\ker(L) \cap \operatorname{Im}(L)=\{0\}$. But when $\lambda \neq 1$, transformation $L$ is not idempotent.

As it turns out, $\ker(L) \cap \operatorname{Im}(L)=\{0\}$ is necessary but not sufficient condition for idempotence of $L$. Instead, the necessary and sufficient condition is given by 
$$\ker(L) \oplus \operatorname{fix}(L)=V$$
where $\operatorname{fix}(L)=\{v \in V|L(v)=v\}$ is the space of fixed points of transformation $L$.

Indeed, if $\ker(L) \oplus \operatorname{fix}(L)=V$, every vector $v \in V$ can be decomposed into sum $v=v_1+v_2$ of vectors $v_1 \in \ker(L)$ and $v_2 \in \operatorname{fix}(L)$, and furthermore 
$$L(v)=L(v_1)+L(v_2)=v_2,\quad L^2(v)=L(v_2)=v_2$$
which means that $L$ is idempotent. If, on the other hand, $L$ is idempotent transformation, $\operatorname{Im}(L)=\operatorname{fix}(L)$ and for any $v \in V$ 
$$L(v-L(v))=L(v)-L^2(v)=0$$
and $v=(v-L(v))+L(v)$ where $v-L(v) \in \ker(L)$ and $L(v) \in \operatorname{Im}(L)=\operatorname{fix}(L)$. Therefore 
$$\ker(L) \oplus \operatorname{fix}(L)=V$$
since $\ker(L) \cap \operatorname{fix}(L)=\{0\}$ by definition of $\operatorname{fix}(L)$.

Comment: I have read somewhere that the fact $\ker(L) \cap \operatorname{Im}(L)=\{0\}$ implies the idempotence of the linear operator... I don't know how to prove it... Look for example the paragraph 3.6 of "handbook of linear algebra" from Leslie Hogben

Comment: If you mean condition 8d, note that it is $V=\ker(T) \oplus \operatorname{fix}(T)$, where $\operatorname{fix}(T)=\{v \in V|T(v)=v\}$, **not** $V=\ker(T) \oplus \operatorname{Im}(T)$.

Comment: When $T$ is idempotent, $\operatorname{fix}(T)=\operatorname{Im}(T)$ as per condition 8c, but in general, this is not the case.

Comment: Sorry, wrong reference. Look at Proposition 4.3.1 in Michael Artin Algebra, 2nd edition

Comment: Well, this is the theorem from the answer you deleted half an hour ago. It does not mention idempotence  at all.

Comment: But look, linear transformation $L$ from my answer above provides a counterexample that $\ker(L) \cap \operatorname{Im}(L)=\{0\}$ does not imply idempotence of $L$.

Comment: I don't seem to get your point. If $L=\lambda x$ then $L^2 = \lambda^2 x^2$ and $x$ is the matrix associated with the linear transformation. If $\text{ker}(L^2)=\text{ker}(L)$ then, we can guess that the matrix associated to the linear transformation is idempotent (since has the same kernel of its square). Then also the linear operator is idempotent. Can you explain things in a clearer way, please? Or maybe suggest me some exercises and/or reference that can help me better understand this point...

Comment: If $L(x)=\lambda x$, then $L^2(x)=\lambda^2 x$. $x$ is not a matrix but a vector to which we are applying transformation $L$.

Comment: If $\lambda \neq 0$, then $\ker(L)=\ker(L^2)=\{0\}$ and $\operatorname{Im}(L)=\operatorname{Im}(L^2)=V$.

Comment: But, if $\lambda \neq 1$, $L \neq L^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation!